# What are the important laravel folders do I need to upload in my host?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to ask an advice. I'm trying to upload my laravel project in ftp using filezilla. I'm confuse. what are the folders do I need to upload? because if i upload all files there are 98,000 files to upload, including the vendors folder and more.Here the list of folders in laravel

```
-app
-bootstrap
-config
-database
-node_modules
-public
-resources
-storage
-tests
-vendors
```

I'm new in laravel. That project is just a practice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use composer to install and download the dependencies on your server?

Comment: I use only the local server using xampp and  my plan is to after I'm done testing in local. I will upload it to my server using filezilla. I can't use the server in my host. I don't know how to used it.

Comment: If you can't access the server other than using ftp, then I guess you just have to upload every one of those files; otherwise find an webhost that gives you access to use composer

Comment: Even when you are uploading all files, there can/will be problems with the generated auto-loader because sometimes absolute paths are used, which do not match the file structure on the host server.

Comment: Also case sensitive can be an issue, between local and live servers

Comment: I see. I will encounter problems if upload files manually?

Comment: 98K files, that's make me crazy in uploading these files. I remove node_modulse as what simon give me an advice, but I will try to solve any problem that I'm gonna encounter after this upload.

Comment: "I don't know how to used it." Well, find out. You'll need to.

Answer (score 1):

i have  few servers where i cannot do a easy ssh/composer etc like i do locally to have to upload manually :-(.

But all i upload are the following folders/files.

```
-app
-bootstrap
-config
-public
-resources
    - views
    - lang
-storage
-vendors
.env
```

You don;t need the node-modules unless your calling anything from with in as these can be huge and time consuming to upload if not required.

hope this helps

Comment: - routes folder is necessary too

Comment: Yes, but this answer was when the routes where in the App/http folder :-), will get to update soon